# How can I tell if an AirPrint printer is available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, printing

I have an option to print in my iPhone app.

On pressing the 'Print' button, `UIPrintInteractionController` is presented. The issue is that I want to show an alert on pressing the print button if no printers are connected.

I tried several options like `[UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]` but these options never worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html):

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable]) {
  //Printing is OK
}
else {
  //Printing is not ok
}
```

Comment: thanks :) it really worked.. till now i was using simulator.. so canPrintData and isPrintingAvailable were not working.. once i used it on device all these were functional :D :P

Comment: I've used these on the simulator. You need to turn on the simulated printer though for it to work. I forget where it is exactly but look through the menu bar of of the simulator application. You can even send print jobs and it will create a PDF to show you how it came out.